# Is it ok to say 'We were wanting to book a trip to Sardinia'?

Tags: verbs, progressive-aspect

> We **were wanting** to book a trip to Sardinia.

Is it ok to say that nowadays?

Comment: Yes. Why do you doubt it? What makes you ask?

Comment: @Ronald Sole Thank you. I was not sure of if "be wanting" is grammatical. That's because I have often been told 'I want an apple', but not 'I am wanting an apple'

Comment: It would usually be used as a periphrastic way of making a request, and in the past tense despite referring to a current desire. Actually, I'll add that to my answer...

Comment: *Some* native speakers would *sometimes* use the continuous participle in this specific context. But most wouldn't - you'd be far more likely to hear it from speakers of "Indian English", who characteristically extend the usage into contexts where mainstream Anglophones would *never* use it. My advice to learners would be to avoid it and stick with Simple Past *We **wanted** to book a trip.*

Comment: I don't know what parts of the UK you've lived in, @FumbleFingers, but both in the parts in which I grew up, and where I now live, it's very common. So is the simple past as you mention, which is also misleading to a non-native because it's referring to a current desire.

Comment: (similarly "I was hoping", "we were wondering", and so on)

Comment: @SamBC: Shifting to past (or "hypothetical", as in *I would think so*) is a common way of "distancing" oneself from a statement in many contexts (often conveying politeness, hesitance, etc.). We don't have the full context here, but I'm assuming the "desire" is in fact definitely *current* (using past tense as a "social interaction device", not semantically significant). Which to my mind works okay with *I was wondering if you had a window seat* or *I was hoping to book a window seat*, but it's not really so good with *We were wanting to book window seats.*

Comment: *Hoping* or *wondering* are appropriate where you don't know if you will be able to. *Wanting* is where you fully expect to be able to do it. Though again, that nuance depends on dialect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another case where the formal understanding of the combination of tense and aspect does not match how it is used.

Formally, that would be used in a description of the past, describe a *want* that was ongoing. However, there's often more natural ways of saying things that express desire or preference without applying the progressive to such verbs. Normally they are used in clauses expressing the way in which such desires or habits influence or explain actions, such as:

> "Wanting to book a trip to Sardinia, they went into the travel agents."

However, at least in some dialects of British English, it would be very common to have the following dialogue when a couple enter a travel agents:

> "Hi, how can I help you?"
>
> "We were wanting to book a trip to Sardinia."

What they mean is "we came here to book a trip to Sardinia", but using *wanting* in that way is very common in some parts of Britain. I suspect it may have been something that once marked less educated speakers, but I don't have evidence for that - and it's now used by people of all sorts.

Essentially, it's usually a periphrastic way of making a request, and in the past tense despite referring to a current desire.